# Optimise arithmetic operations on very large numbers

Tags: java, biginteger, largenumber

I want to compute the function H(n)
where

```
H(0)=0;
H(i)=H(i-1)×A+Ci mod B;

10<=A,B<=10^15;
```

C is an array of n elements

The following code takes too much time...any better way of doing this?

```
public BigInteger H(int no) {              
    if(no>0) {
        bi=H(no-1);
        bi=bi.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(A));
        bi=bi.add(BigInteger.valueOf(c[no-1]));
        bi=bi.remainder(BigInteger.valueOf(B));
        return bi;
    }

    return BigInteger.ZERO;
```

}

Comment: What is the nature of Ci; what is its length, is it effectively random, does it contain a lot of zeroes, similar values, or similar patterns? If so, a change of algorithm may speed up things.

Comment: It seems there are some parentheses missing in the formula.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a dynamic programming approach.  Rather than using recursion, loop starting at the initial case H(0) and moving up from there.  Example:

```
public static BigInteger H(BigInteger[] c, int no, BigInteger A, BigInteger B) {

    if (c.length < no - 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("no is too large");
    }

    BigInteger bi = BigInteger.ZERO;  // Initial case H(0) = 0

    for (int i = 1; i <= no; i++) {   // From H(1) -> H(no)
        bi = bi.multiply(A).add(c[i - 1]).remainder(B);
    }

    return bi;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try **not using the remainder every iteration**, it uses division which is **VERY** slow.

You should also not use BigInteger.valueOf() every iteration. **Only create A and B as BigIntegers one time and save them**, there is no need for doing it more times.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, welcome to the world of BigIntegers.

One thing I remember is that you can do two paths for this:

1) A slow path with BigIntegers
2) A fast path with double primitive types when both the arguments are less than Max Double.

That should pump up the speed a little bit.

Tell us here how it went and post times if you can. This is really interesting.